# If $m$ tickets are drawn out of $n$ tickets numbered $1$ to $n$, find variance of the sum of the numbers on tickets

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance

> $m$ tickets are drawn out of $n$ tickets which are numbered from $1$ to $n$. If $X$ denote the sum of the numbers on the tickets drawn. Find $V(X)$.

$X = X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_m$ , if $X_i$ can be treated as the $i$th number drawn.
Otherwise, $X_i$ can be treated as the indicator variable of the number $i=1,2,...,n$.

In either way, I am able to get expectation since dependence of variables does not matter. However, while calculating Variance, dependence does matter. While calculating $E(X_iX_j)$ the second draw is supposed to be dependent on the first draw since there is a constraint of the sum $X$.

Please answer.

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to format math](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on this site.

Comment: Maybe there is a clever way to get the variance by combinatorial methods, but I don't see it. For $n = 10; m = 5,$ simulation in R with `x = replicate(10^6, sum(sample(1:10, 5))); mean(x); var(x)` returns $E(X) \approx 27.5,$ which I hope matches what you have for the mean, and $V(X) \approx 22.95,$ which should be accurate to three significant digits. // Maybe you could generate more interest if you showed your method for the mean and discussed topics covered just before this problem appears.

Comment: Somewhat sketchy hint: Seems possible values `v`are 15 through 40, corresponding probabilities are $f=(1,1,2,3,5,7,9,11,14,16,18,19,20,20,19,18,16,14,11,9,7,5,3,2,1,1)/{10\choose 5}.$ Then $\mu$ is `sum(f*v)` =27.5, and $\sigma^2$ = `sum(f*v^2) - 27.5^2` = 22.91667.

Comment: I have tried using an indicator variable technique and I got E(X)=m(n+1)/2 and by an approximation I obtained V(X)=m(n+1)(n-5)/12 (the error in approximation being 0.066 in case of n=10, m=5)

Comment: Previously asked: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/972267/321264.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Here is a slightly indirect way of obtaining the variance:*

Let $X_k$ be the number on the $k$th ticket, $k=1,2,\ldots,m$.

So we have a uniform distribution for the $X_k$'s, namely

$$ P(X_k=j)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{n}&,\text{ if }j=1,2,\cdots,n\\\\\,0&,\text{ otherwise }\end{cases}$$

So,

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(X_k)&=E(X_k^2)-(E(X_k))^2
\\\\&=\frac{n^2-1}{12}=\sigma^2\,,\text{ say }
\end{align}

If the correlation between $X_i$ and $X_j$ $\,(i\ne j)$ be $\rho$, then $$\rho=\dfrac{\text{Cov}(X_i,X_j)}{\sigma^2}$$

You are looking for \begin{align}\operatorname{Var}(X)&=\operatorname{Var}\left(\sum_{k=1}^m X_k\right)\\&=\sum_{k=1}^m \operatorname{Var}(X_k)+2\sum_{i<j}\text{Cov}(X_i,X_j)\\&=m\sigma^2+2\binom{m}{2}\rho\sigma^2
\\&=m\sigma^2(1+(m-1)\rho)\tag{1}\end{align}

Now note that the joint distribution of $(X_i,X_j)\,,i\ne j$ is independent of $m$.

So we see that

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\color{red}{n}}X_k\right)&=\operatorname{Var}(\text{constant})=0
\\&\implies\color{red}{n}\sigma^2(1+(\color{red}{n}-1)\rho)=0
\\&\implies\rho=\frac{1}{1-n}
\end{align}

Substituting this value of $\rho$ and the value of $\sigma^2$ in $(1)$, we finally get the variance of $X$ as

$$\operatorname{Var}(X)=\frac{m(n+1)(n-m)}{12}$$

Comment: That's really slick.

Comment: Hello! Why do you assume that $P(X_k=j)=\frac{1}{n}$? I mean, I agree it is true if $k=1$. But from the $k=2$. Probability of $j$ being taken changes. It then become equal to $\frac{1}{n-1}$. I know, we have a lot of ways to select the first element. And then if we consider all possible ways to choose the first one, it mathematically(I've done some calculation) it follows that the $P(X_2=j)=\frac{1}{n}$. But to do the same proof for the case $k=3$(and then for arbitrary $k$) is much more complex. Can you explain why do you think we can make this assumption(please don't say 'by symmetry')

Comment: Think about it in this way- Say that you have closed your eyes till now and during each draw(WOR) you put the units in m different cardboard boxes and are now going to open them. Now in this case, the probability of getting a success remains constant for each of the units as you progressively open the cardboard boxes.