# Mathematical expectation, variance

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance

The basket contains N numbered balls $1; 2; ...; N$. From the basket without
returns $n<=N$ balls are retrieved. Let S denote the sum of numbers a moat of taken out balls. Find the mathematical expectation E (S) and the variance
this Var (S) of this sum.

**Solution:**

I wanted to clarify, to solve this problem, you need to write a distribution and then start counting and if you need a distribution, then which one?

Comment: The expectation is easy.  The variance is harder, but will probably be a polynomial function of $N$ and $n$.  Personally I would experiment to find that polynomial

Comment: @Henry Can you tell me how to find this polynomial, where and what to read, since unfortunately I cannot imagine it

Comment: Try small N and n first.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin Can you explain in a little more detail what you mean?

Comment: For example if $n=1$ the variance is $\frac1{12}(N^2-1)$

Comment: Where did $1/12$ come from?

Comment: When n=1, the distribution of S is rather obvious and well known.

Comment: Do I need to set the distribution correctly now, so that I can then calculate everything that is needed?

Comment: Let $X_i$ be the number on the $i$-th ball picked, for $i=1,2,\ldots, n$. Note that by symmetry, $X_{i}\sim Uniform(\{1,2,\ldots,N\})$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots, n$ and for any $k\in \{1,2,\ldots,N\}$, we have that conditional on $X_{i}=k$, $X_{j}$ is uniformly distributed on $\{1,2,\ldots,N\} \backslash \{k\}$ (for $j\ne i$). You can use these facts (and the law of total expectation where necessary) to work out $\Bbb{E}[X_{i}], \mathrm{Var}(X_{i}), \Bbb{E}[X_{i}X_{j}], \mathrm{Cov}(X_{i}, X_{j})$, and thus ultimately the mean and variance of the sum $S_{n} := X_{1} + \cdots + X_{n}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't understand at all what this is about. I understood the train of your thoughts, but I don’t understand how to count.

Comment: I think that if $n=2$ the variance might be $\frac16(N^2-N-2)$.  So my heroic guess before I look any further is that the general expression may be something like $\frac1{12}n(N+1)(N-n)$.  The $\frac1{12}$ looks familiar as the variance of a continuous uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.  The $(N-n)$ term looks familiar from the *finite population correction* for the standard error.

Comment: @Henry Also, your expression is symmetric with respect to $n\leftrightarrow N-n$, which is a good sign.

Comment: Can you please show how you calculated the mathematical expectation, perhaps then it will become clearer

Comment: This is answered at  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2813390/321264 and its linked posts.