# Exercise 3.4.2 Grimmett and Stirzaker (probability theory)

Tags: probability, proof-explanation, expected-value, variance

> An urn contains $n$ balls numbered $1,2, ... , n$. We remove $k$ balls at random (without replacement) and add up their numbers. Find the mean and variance of the total.
> [image]

The image is the solution of the question. But the algebra is too complicated to me. I think that the first equality in the display, it should be $2k(k-1) E(X_1 X_2)$. Am I right? I also do not understand how he get from the second to third and the third to the fourth equation. Can you help me understand these steps? I guess that the authors use $\sum_{i <j} = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j = i+1}^n = n(n-1)$. I understand that the first equality, but how can we show the second equality?

Comment: Previous discussions of this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3286112/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2813390/321264.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When expanding $(\sum_1^k X_i)^2$ the cross terms have the form $X_i X_j$ where $i\ne j$. There are $k^2-k$ of these cross terms, and they all have the same expectation, so no, there is no $2$ missing. A $2$ reappears in the next sum because
$$
E(X_1X_2) = \sum_{i\ne j} ij \,P(X_1=i, X_2=j)=2\sum_{i>j}ij\,P(X_1=i,X_2=j).\tag1
$$
For the first algebra step, the authors are writing 
$$\sum_{i>j} ij = \sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=j+1}^nij=\sum_{j=1}^n j \left(\sum_{i=1}^ni -\sum_{i=1}^j i\right).\tag2
$$
They evaluate $\sum j^2$ by writing $\sum j^2 = \sum j(j+1) - \sum j$. They introduce $\sum j(j+1)$ because this sum has a nice form:
$$\sum_{j=1}^n j(j+1)=\frac13 n(n+1)(n+2)\tag3$$
 since the identity
$$j(j+1)(j+2)-(j-1)(j)(j+1) = 3j(j+1)\tag4$$
means that (3) is a telescoping sum and can be evaluated painlessly.

As for the final step, the sum $\sum j[n(n+1)- j(j+1)]$ is evaluated in the form
$$
n(n+1)\left(\sum j\right) - \left(\sum j(j+1)(j+2)\right)+2\left(\sum j(j+1)\right)\tag5
$$
using the same telescoping trick to obtain the nice form
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n j(j+1)(j+2) = \frac14 n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3).\tag6
$$
The rest is boring algebra, as they say.